# Select2 is not working with elements added via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new `<select class="js-select-search">` element on the page through AJAX, but it seems that a standard call in that way doesn't work:

```
$('.js-select-search').select2();
```

I understand that it's a new element in the DOM, but I don't get how to make it work.

Comment: Read the doc, it's well explained https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: You need to instantiate the `select2()` library on the elements ***after*** you append them to the DOM in your AJAX callback.

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis That's about using an AJAX source for the Select2 data, not quite what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 is a function. It runs once, and then never again. You can run it again however in the 'success' part of your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
   success: function () {
      $('.js-select-search').select2();
   }
})
```